# Systemd timer and mount not found

Tags: fedora, systemd, systemd-timer

I'm trying to set up a systemd time that runs every 4 hours. When the timer fires a script is run to update some data files. I followed [systemd timer every 2 hours at 30 minutes past the hour?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/396605/56041) and [systemd timer every 15 minutes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126786/56041).

File `/etc/systemd/system/ftc-data.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Fetch FTC Do Not Call data files

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/var/ftc/ftc-data/fetch-data.sh
```

File `/etc/systemd/system/ftc-data.timer`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run ftc-data.service every 4 hours

[Timer]
OnCalendar=00/4:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Here's where the problems arise:

```
systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/ftc-data.timer
systemctl start  /etc/systemd/system/ftc-data.timer
systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/ftc-data.service
```

The commands result in:

```
# systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/ftc-data.timer

# systemctl start  /etc/systemd/system/ftc-data.timer
Failed to start etc-systemd-system-ftc\x2ddata.timer.mount: Unit etc-systemd-system-ftc\x2ddata.timer.mount not found.

# systemctl enable /etc/systemd/system/ftc-data.service
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
4) In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
   instance name specified.
```

It looks like the problems start when trying to enable `ftc-data.timer`. I'm trying to make sense of *`Failed to start etc-systemd-system-ftc\x2ddata.timer.mount: Unit etc-systemd-system-ftc\x2ddata.timer.mount not found.`* but I am not finding hits when searching for it. I found one post at [Newbie Corner » Unit timer](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=235036), but the fellow went back to using cron because timers are so f**k'd up with systemd.

Here is the [systemd.mount](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) docs, but damn if I can tell what's wrong with things after reading it. I have no idea what a filesystem mount has to do with things. All I want to do is run a script every 4 hours.

I'm really missing `cron` around now. `cron` is simple and just works. It has been replaced with something more complicated that does not work. Sigh...

What needs to be fixed (besides systemd)?

---

This is a Fedora 29 Server and SELinux is in enforcing mode. This may have something to do with things:

```
# ls -Zd /var/ftc/ftc-data/fetch-data.sh
unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/ftc/ftc-data/fetch-data.sh
```

The web server has access to `/var/ftc/ftc-data/` because it needs to serve documents from the directory Also see [How to troubleshoot Nginx permission denied in subdirectory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/508981/56041)

Answer (score 5):

You're meant to provide the *name* of the unit, not the path to a file.

You should have done instead:

```
systemctl enable ftc-data.timer
systemctl start ftc-data.timer
systemctl enable ftc-data.service
```